# Crystal Formula: If/then/else statement with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, if-statement, crystal-reports

I am writing a formula for crystal so I can get a count of when certain criteria are met. Here is my statement:

```
IF {eResponse.eResponse.05}=2205001 AND

 ({eSituation.esituation.11}="I20.9" or {eSituation_12.eSituation.12}="I20.9")
AND 
  ({eDisposition_HospitalTeamActivationGroup.eDisposition.24}=4224013 or not(isnull({eDisposition_HospitalTeamActivationGroup.eDisposition.25})))
then 1
else 0;
```

I am still getting some fields that are blank for this formula, which I know shouldn't be the case. How would you correct it so I only return 1's or 0's?

Thanks!

Comment: Please share erroneous fields in your post or comment below

Comment: I was creating a new formula field in the crystal report named Notification. So that field should have been giving me a 0 or a 1 if a patient met the criteria above. I think part of the issue is that none of the eSituation.11 or esituation.12 fields meet the "I20.9 criteria" (if you look at the data output). But shouldn't that mean all of the patients get a 0 in the formula field instead of a blank?

Comment: A blank result in this formula will only be returned when the formula "crashes". This usually happens because of NULL-values. So you have to check the columns by using `IsNull` before comparing them with the criteria. (From my experience, the isnull-check needs to be in a separate if-statement otherwise the formula will crash anyway.)